# Compare two string sets in java and output binary (matches/not) array

Tags: java, set

I have an ordered list `A` and a string set `B` in Java. I need the comparision output to be in the form of a binary array. For example if `A` was `{a,b,c,d,e}` and `B` was `{a,d,e}`, my output should be an array `[1,0,0,1,1]`. How can i achieve this efficiently without resorting to brute force checking? I'm dealing with quite a large number of sets(large in size too) to compare with A.

Comment: ur example is not clear. how it is [1,0,0,1,1]?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense unless the sets are sorted, because otherwise how will you know which of the output bits relates to which of the objects in the Set? Or do you actually mean that the input sets are _arrays_? Please clarify.

Comment: At least set A needs to be ordered; otherwise, what does the output mean?

Comment: will `{a,b,c,d,e}` and `{a,d,b}` produce [1,1,0,1,0] ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear before. A can be treated as a list(ordered). @kalpa : yup it would.

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sort of *sets* are these? Normally sets don't have any order.

It feels like essentially we need to treat `B` as a set but `A` as a list. For example, you might use:

```
List<String> a = ...;
Set<String> b = ...;

boolean result = new boolean[a.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  result[i] = b.contains(a);
}
```

So long as the set implementation is a fast one (e.g. `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`) this should be an O(n) operation where n is the size of `a`. It's hard to see how you could do significantly better given that you need to produce n results...

Comment: Yes, 'A' can be treated as a list. Well the scenario is this. I am working on a text classification problem and for each document, i need to compare it with a dictionary list. The problem is that the documents and the dictionary are quite large in size. The number of documents is also pretty huge. So, i was hoping for a more efficient implimentation than O(n), hopefully some existing third party libs which can help me do that.

Comment: @ananthv: How are you expecting anything to populate an array of size `n` in less than O(n)? If `b` will always be *much smaller* than `a` then there may be ways of doing better, particularly if you'll be doing this operation several times with different `b` lists but the same `a` list. You need to clarify your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll have to brute force it, but it's quite trivial...

something like:

```
String a = "abcde";
String b = "ade";

BitSet setBits = new BitSet();

// Now iterate over
for(int i =0; i < a.length(); ++i)
{
  setBits.set(i, b.indexOf(a.charAt(i)) != -1);
}
```

Tweaked to answer case of treating the second string as a "set".